AWS fargate ecs ssm: Unable to start a Port Forwarding Session To Remote Host on a fargate ecs container, yet can do so on an instance
Im unable to start a Port Forwarding Session To Remote Host (or simply remote session) on a fargate ecs container, yet can do so on an instance. Using AWS console (thats the website based and not shell based) I cant seem to figure out what settings are needed.
Working (instance remote session):
aws ssm start-session \
--target i-{instance} \
--region {region} \
--profile {profile} \
--document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
--parameters '{"portNumber":["22"],"localPortNumber":["9999"],"host":["{host}"]}'

Not working the same on on a conatiner:
aws ssm start-session \
--target ecs:{clusterName}_{taskId}_{containerRuntimeId} \
--region {region} \
--profile {profile} \
--document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
--parameters '{"portNumber":["22"],"localPortNumber":["9999"],"host":["{PrivateIPofClusterTask}"]}'

Any idea?
I even created a iam policy and attached to the iam roles that run the specific service and tasks inside ecs cluster.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:StartSession",
                "ecs:ExecuteCommand"
            ],
            
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecs:blablabla:cluster/{clusterName}",
                "arn:aws:ssm:blablabla::document/AWS-StartInteractiveCommand",
                "arn:aws:ssm:blablabla::document/AWS-StartPortForwardingSession",
                "arn:aws:ssm:blablabla::document/AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost",
                "arn:aws:ssm:blablabla::document/AWS-StartSSHSession"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


Because it is ECS Fargate, you better use Amazon ECS Exec.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html
aws ecs execute-command \
    --cluster ${YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME} \
    --task ${YOUR_TASK_ID} \
    --container ${YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME} \
    --interactive \
    --command "/bin/sh"

There are some considerations and prerequisites, please read them carefully and ensure that the Session Manager plugin is installed.

Ive actually figured it out.
Lets assume the following setup:
ECS > Cluster > Service > Task(s) > Container.
The solution involves the following steps:
(suppose we use port 22 for SSH)

Update ECS Task Definition:

Add port 22 to portMappings in the Task Definition of your "Service" are focusing on. Upon saving, you will get a new "Revision" of the Task Definition.


Update ECS Cluster Service:

Ensure its using the Task Definition's latest "Revision" you just created.
Ensure only 1 "Desired tasks" is set and you have uncheck the “Use service auto scaling” also. Otherwise you will have to ssh into as many tasks.
Kill the current running task (assuming you are NOT all this in production env), and deploy / start a new one. Ensure its using the new Task Definition revision.
enable-execute-command via shell using aws ecs update-service


IAM Policy:

Create a new Allow policy with AWS-StartSSHSession document under the Resource (see the one in the question). The only Action you need is "ssm:StartSession"
Add various items under condition as per need for added security
Attach the Roles running the Task to this Policy


SSM into the container:

aws ssm start-session with target and profile only. No need for document and parameters. The target is "ecs:{clusterName}_{taskId}_{containerRuntimeId}"
If this doesnt work, see if you can aws ecs execute-command any command such as --command "ls -lt".
install start sshd. If you have alpine image, you would have to spend bit of extra efforts on sshd setup which is a complete seperate topic on its own.
create a new user, or use public/private key. This topic is also beyond this discussion and you need to study sshd for that
only allow this user to ssh into the container for added security


SSH from your system:

make sure you are already logged in via aws sso login --profile {myProfile}.
Here is a ssh config item, it uses ProxyCommand:
Host loremIpsumSSHProfile
    HostName loremIpsumSite
    User loremIpsumUser
    ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target {myTarget} -- 
    profile {myProfile} --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession"





You could obviously just use SSM, but the remote debugging tools such xdebug would need SSH (as far as I can tell).
